# How to write path in flask of folder in remote server

Tags: python, rest, flask, server, zip

I'm creating a RESTful service using Flask,that parses files into a .zip folder, and I want to return that file. this is a snippet of the code.

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
import zipfile

       @app.route('/get_files', methods=['GET'])
       def download():
         zf = zipfile.ZipFile('gen.zip', mode = 'w')
         zf.write('generated/file1.c')
         zf.write('generated/file2.c')
         zf.write('generated/file3.c')
         zf.write('generated/file4.h')
         zf.close()
         return send_from_directory(/home/localadmin/test", "gen.zip", as_attachment=True)
```

it's working perfectly on localhost. when I run it on a remote server, I get 404 Not Found. So I think the issue is from the path to the directory?

EDIT:
I have tried returning a string instead of the generated files, and it's working perfectly too. what comes to my mind are two issues:
1. the path to the server directory is wrong
2. the server's proxy configurations does not permit file downloads maybe?

Comment: What URL are you attempting to reach on the remote server, and where is the 404 message appearing?  What corresponding messages appear in the remote server's error and/or log files?

Comment: 404 error means that the endpoint does not exist ("your_server_address:your_port/get_files"). If your api cannot find a directory on the server, it will be a server error, which is a 500 error.

Comment: @CODE-REaD it appears as an HTML response when I try to contact the server via Postman or curl.

Comment: What happens if instead of trying to read data, you just return "Hello". Given your error code (404), you should get the same error, because the problem is with your end point.

Comment: I have tried to return "Hello" and it's working just fine